# Strip HTML Formatting from R Strings

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape information from this url: `http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/index.cgi?month=2&day=3&year=2017` and have gotten decently far to the point where I have strings for each game that look like this:

```
str <-"Yale\n\t\t\t87\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tFinal\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\tColumbia\n\t\t\t78\n\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\n\t\t"
```

Ideally I'd like to get to a vector or dataframe that looks something like:

```
str_vec <- c('Yale',87,'Columbia',78)
```

I've tried a few things that didn't work like:

```
without_n <- gsub(x = str, pattern = '\n')
without_Final <- gsub(x = without_n, pattern = 'Final')
str_vec <- strslpit(x = without_Final, split = '\t')
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful tips/answers!

Comment: why is `Final` not in the expected output?

Comment: it's a list of basketball scores from last February. hopefully by now all the games should be over!

Comment: `strsplit(str, '\\s+')[[1]]`, but it's be better to scrape properly in the first place. On that note, though, check the terms.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. I'm just using this to learn scraping but I guess I'll find another site to use...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to first replace all the non-alphanumeric characters in the string with an empty string. Then insert a `space` between the name and score. Thereafter you can split the string on `space` to a data structure needed.

```
require(stringr)

step_1 <- gsub('([^[:alnum:]]|(Final))', "", str)
#"Yale87Columbia78"

step_2 <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)", "\\1 \\2 ", step_1)
strsplit(str_trim(step_2)," ")
#"Yale" "87" "Columbia" "78"
```

I assume the string pattern is consistent, for this to work reliably.